# Using distinct , Case and order by in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, case, distinct

I have a requirements  to retrieve users mobile numbers from the database without duplicates so i'm using **distinct** key word to do that.

Also not all mobile numbers are well formatted so I'm using Case to format the numbers.

Lastly I want to get the latest 500 mobile numbers so I wanted to order it by Order by ID desc but it shows

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

below is my query

```
 select distinct top 500  case 

                     when len(PhoneNumber) = 13 And phoneNumber  like '+311%' then replace(PhoneNumber, '+311', '0')
                     when len(PhoneNumber) = 13 And phoneNumber  like '311-%' then replace(PhoneNumber, '311-', '0')

                     when len(PhoneNumber) = 13 And phoneNumber  like '0311%' then stuff(PhoneNumber, 1, 4 , 0 )

                     when len(PhoneNumber) = 14 And phoneNumber  like '00311%'then stuff(PhoneNumber, 1, 5 ,'0')
                     when len(PhoneNumber) = 14 And phoneNumber  like '00311%' then stuff(PhoneNumber, 1, 4 ,'0')


                     when len(PhoneNumber) = 12 And phoneNumber  like '311%' then stuff(PhoneNumber, 1 , 3 , '0')
                     when len(PhoneNumber) = 12 then REPLACE (PhoneNumber, '-', '')

                     when len(PhoneNumber) = 11 And phoneNumber  like '00%' then Stuff(PhoneNumber, 1, 2 , '0')
                     else PhoneNumber
                end 


from users where  cityid = 1 and statusid = 1  and  (len(PhoneNumber) >= 10 And len(PhoneNumber) <= 14) 
and PhoneNumber not like '"%' and PhoneNumber not like '+311-%' and PhoneNumber not like '01%'
and PhoneNumber  like '0%'

Order by id
```

**UPDATE**

As Metal suggested , I'm using row_number() and partition by it gives me one mobile number , Which is not correct result

```
select top 500000 Mobile
from 
    (select 
        row_number() over (partition by PhoneNumber order by id desc) rn,
        case 
        when len(PhoneNumber) = 13 And phoneNumber  like '+966%' then replace(PhoneNumber, '+966', '0')
        when len(PhoneNumber) = 13 And phoneNumber  like '966-%' then replace(PhoneNumber, '966-', '0')
        when len(PhoneNumber) = 13 And phoneNumber  like '0966%' then stuff(PhoneNumber, 1, 4 , 0 )
        when len(PhoneNumber) = 14 And phoneNumber  like '00966%'then stuff(PhoneNumber, 1, 5 ,'0')
        when len(PhoneNumber) = 14 And phoneNumber  like '0096%' then stuff(PhoneNumber, 1, 4 ,'0')
        when len(PhoneNumber) = 12 And phoneNumber  like '966%' then stuff(PhoneNumber, 1 , 3 , '0')
        when len(PhoneNumber) = 12 then REPLACE (PhoneNumber, '-', '')
        when len(PhoneNumber) = 11 And phoneNumber  like '00%' then Stuff(PhoneNumber, 1, 2 , '0')
        else PhoneNumber
        end  as Mobile
    from consigneeDetail 
    where  cityid = 1 and statusid = 1  and  (len(PhoneNumber) >= 10 And len(PhoneNumber) <= 14) 
            and PhoneNumber not like '"%' and PhoneNumber not like '+966-%' and PhoneNumber not like '01%'
            and PhoneNumber  like '0%') t1
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `subquery` instead, then `row_number()` to get distinct values.

```
select top 500 t2.col1 from (
    select row_number() over (partition by t1.col1 order by id desc) rn, t1.col1
    from 
        (select         
            id,
            case 
            when len(PhoneNumber) = 13 And phoneNumber  like '+311%' then replace(PhoneNumber, '+311', '0')
            when len(PhoneNumber) = 13 And phoneNumber  like '311-%' then replace(PhoneNumber, '311-', '0')
            when len(PhoneNumber) = 13 And phoneNumber  like '0311%' then stuff(PhoneNumber, 1, 4 , 0 )
            when len(PhoneNumber) = 14 And phoneNumber  like '00311%'then stuff(PhoneNumber, 1, 5 ,'0')
            when len(PhoneNumber) = 14 And phoneNumber  like '00311%' then stuff(PhoneNumber, 1, 4 ,'0')
            when len(PhoneNumber) = 12 And phoneNumber  like '311%' then stuff(PhoneNumber, 1 , 3 , '0')
            when len(PhoneNumber) = 12 then REPLACE (PhoneNumber, '-', '')
            when len(PhoneNumber) = 11 And phoneNumber  like '00%' then Stuff(PhoneNumber, 1, 2 , '0')
            else PhoneNumber
            end  as col1
        from users 
        where  cityid = 1 and statusid = 1  and  (len(PhoneNumber) >= 10 And len(PhoneNumber) <= 14) 
                and PhoneNumber not like '"%' and PhoneNumber not like '+311-%' and PhoneNumber not like '01%'
                and PhoneNumber  like '0%') t1
    ) t2 
where t2.rn = 1
```

Comment: @rav, forgot the alias, try again

Comment: I tried , it only returns one record , which is incorrect

Comment: what do you mean by rn = 1? and why you include t1?

Comment: try again, its just a substitute of top X

Comment: You rock! records is coming but how can I make sure they are unique? I'm little worried

Comment: What do you mean by col1? cause I'm replacing it with PhoneNumber (which is the name of the column)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT phonenumber 
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN Len(phonenumber) = 13 
                      AND phonenumber LIKE '+311%' THEN 
                 REPLACE(phonenumber, '+311', '0') 
                 WHEN Len(phonenumber) = 13 
                      AND phonenumber LIKE '311-%' THEN 
                 REPLACE(phonenumber, '311-', '0') 
                 WHEN Len(phonenumber) = 13 
                      AND phonenumber LIKE '0311%' THEN 
                 Stuff(phonenumber, 1, 4, 0) 
                 WHEN Len(phonenumber) = 14 
                      AND phonenumber LIKE '00311%'THEN 
                 Stuff(phonenumber, 1, 5, '0') 
                 WHEN Len(phonenumber) = 14 
                      AND phonenumber LIKE '00311%' THEN 
                 Stuff(phonenumber, 1, 4, '0') 
                 WHEN Len(phonenumber) = 12 
                      AND phonenumber LIKE '311%' THEN 
                 Stuff(phonenumber, 1, 3, '0') 
                 WHEN Len(phonenumber) = 12 THEN REPLACE (phonenumber, '-', '') 
                 WHEN Len(phonenumber) = 11 
                      AND phonenumber LIKE '00%' THEN 
                 Stuff(phonenumber, 1, 2, '0') 
                 ELSE phonenumber 
               end AS phonenumber 
        FROM   users 
        WHERE  cityid = 1 
               AND statusid = 1 
               AND ( Len(phonenumber) >= 10 
                     AND Len(phonenumber) <= 14 ) 
               AND phonenumber NOT LIKE '"%' 
               AND phonenumber NOT LIKE '+311-%' 
               AND phonenumber NOT LIKE '01%' 
               AND phonenumber LIKE '0%' 
        ORDER  BY id) 
LIMIT  500
```

Comment: I don't want to include the id in the select statements cause that may give me a duplicate mobile numbers , one user can have 2 records with different id and same mobile number , With distinct it will consider it as unique since the ids are different

Comment: Updated for your requirement using sub query

Comment: @rav were you able to check?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct' Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.